# Not able to login into DotNetNuke website

Tags: dotnetnuke

We have been working on DotNetNuke for past 3-4 months, when we had installed DNN we had given host username and password, using which we had installed several modules later on, but lately we are facing a strange issue, when we try to login as host, login does not seem to work, and no errors are reported, screen remains as it is, as though nothing has been done, I can still see Login link and no host related Menu bar, I even tried to register a new user and then login and nothing seems to happen. To me it seems Login functionality somehow stopped woking[image: Screen shot after loggin in]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: @EfficionDave, sorry its a intranet site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that, i had changed authentication type to Windows in Config file that caused all the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to see the Login control on the page? If not, try going to http://mywebsite/?ctl=login and login using the login module there.

Comment: Tried it, but nothing happened, got directed to the firstpage, and still no Host related menu bar.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. In my local IIS, I changed Forms Authentication to Enabled and was able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using DNN 6.x, my best guess is that there is some kind of a Javascript conflict that is preventing the login popup from working. Perhaps one of the modules you installed is causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection string in your web.config file to ensure the user id, password, and db name are correct. It will be in two locations, one will look like

```
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SOME_CATALOG;User Id=someuser;Password=SOME_PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And the other will look like

```
<add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SOME_CATALOG;User Id=someuser;Password=SOME_PASSWORD" />
```

I had the login problem and discovered that the user ID was incorrect in one place.